# Fatal Error at local:////v1/xsl/ProcessRequest.xsl: Missing@Value

Tags: xslt, soap, attributes

I am getting this response from backend. while trying to extract the value of the element `<s:Detail>`, getting Fatal error in my xslt:`Missing @value`.

Here is my incoming error response from backend

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
            xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
            xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1"/>
        <o:Security xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:mustUnderstand="1">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2018-04-04T04:46:42.182Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2018-04-04T04:51:42.182Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value xmlns:a="urn:epicsystems.com:Interconnect.2004-05.Faults">a:ApplicationFault</s:Value>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">No patient ID provided.</s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
            <s:Detail>
                <ApplicationFault xmlns="urn:epicsystems.com:Interconnect.2004-05.Faults" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                    <Type>MissingInputParameter</Type>
                </ApplicationFault>
            </s:Detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

i am trying to fetch the value using the xslt code

```
<xsl:if test= "$sendResponse/*[local-name()='url-open']/*[local-name()='response']/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Fault']"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="urn:systems.com:connect.2004-05.Faults" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
     xmlns="urn:systems.com:connect.2004-05.Faults"
     xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <xsl:variable name="statusCode" select="$sendResponse/*[local-name()='url-open']/*[local-name()='response']/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Fault']/*[local-name()='Detail']"/>
</xsl:if>.
```

Not sure where am in going wrong. Can anybody please assist me on this issue?.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding namespace declarations to an `xsl:if` element? That makes no sense. Better add them to the `xsl:stylesheet` root element.

You will have to re-add `$sendResponse/*[local-name()='url-open']/*[local-name()='response']/` at the beginning to conform with your requirements. But for this example this is not necessary.

The following stylesheet prints the `Type` value of your SOAP response. You should get the gist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:s  ="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a  ="urn:systems.com:connect.2004-05.Faults" 
    xmlns:u  ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:f  ="urn:epicsystems.com:Interconnect.2004-05.Faults" xmlns:xi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="statusCode" select="s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Fault/s:Detail/f:ApplicationFault/f:Type" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$statusCode" />
        <xsl:if test="$statusCode">
            Value is present!
        </xsl:if>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
MissingInputParameter
Value is present!
```